# Vuex: using moduled Mutations and vuex's createNamespacedHelpers API

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Just wondering, what would be the equivalent of this:

```
this.$store.commit('surfGroups/SET_CREATING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING', true);
```

Using the createNamespacedHelpers API:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex';

const { mapMutations } = createNamespacedHelpers('surfGroups/');
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex';
const { mapMutations } = createNamespacedHelpers('surfGroups');
```

and then in your `methods:`

```
methods: {
  ...mapMutations({myMutation: 'SET_CREATING_SURF_GROUP_LOADING'})
}
```

next, in your code you need to call this mutation:

```
this.myMutation(true)
```

Vuex docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components